# Why $1/(1+e^{-x}) = e^x/(1+e^x)$

Tags: logistic, sigmoid-curve

I am currently learning the sigmoid/logistic function and have completely forgotten how the maths behind this equivalence works:

$$
\dfrac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} = \dfrac{e^{x}}{1+e^{x}}
$$

By this I mean how the left side equates with the right side. I know that the left side is simply multiplied by (1/exp(x)) but what are the rules governing this?
Any help would be much appreciated, especially the rules so that I can revisit them.

Comment: $\dfrac a b =\dfrac ab \times \dfrac cc = \dfrac{ac}{bc}$ for $b,c \not=0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is easy.

$ \dfrac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} = \dfrac{e^{x}}{1+e^{x}} $

Consider lhs

$ \dfrac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{e^{x}}} $

which is equal to

$ \dfrac{e^{x}}{e^{x}+ 1} $

Comment: Multiply by $e^x/e^x$ To get to the final line.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} &=\dfrac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} \cdot \frac{e^x}{ e^x} \\
 &= \dfrac{e^{x}}{e^x+1} \end{align} $$

- Multiplying a number by 1 doesn't change its value, and $\frac{e^x}{ e^x}$ is just one way to write 1.
- Multiplication *adds* exponents of a common base: $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$. We use this in the final line to get $e^x \cdot e^{-x}=e^0 = 1$.